# show a picture in memory of AVD ..using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to draw a line on a picture in memory of android device and show it.I put a picture in sdcard of AVD . I installed `opencv` libraries and they worked. But I don't know how to draw a line on a picture by OpenCV on android and for showing a picture I have problem. My codes doesn't have any error.But when I run app in AVD my App had been stopped by android ! My codes are:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    **@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Mat a=Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/img5.jpg");

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(a.cols(), a.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(a, bm);
        ImageView iw=new ImageView(this);
        iw.setImageBitmap(bm);
        setContentView(iw);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use any opencv code in onCreate() .

since it is dependant on native libs, you've got to wait , until they were properly loaded (until mLoaderCallback *returns*).

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        if (status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS ) {
            //
            // now we can call opencv code !
            //
        } else {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
    }
```

onCameraViewStarted() might be the best place to put your code (with a camera setup).

Comment: Should I create a new method and add this code to it? I don't need camera yet. I want to read a picture of sdcard by imread and detect a object by opencv on it and show processed picture

Comment: ah, ok. was more guessing from the cam-setup. hope, you like the edit ;)

Comment: Should I add this function to 'mainActivity.java' or add new class and put to it?

Comment: is this your [first opencv program](http://answers.opencv.org/question/16993/display-image/) ?